# C# StreamReader marking question

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader

What I am trying to do is remember where I am in an input stream and later go back there.
It is very simple in java using mark() and reset(), but I do not know how to make possible this in c#. There is no such method.

for example

```
public int peek() 
{
    try 
    {
        file.x; //in java file.mark(1)
        int tmp = file.read();
        file.+ //in java file.reset();
        return tmp;
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {} 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Indeed there isn't that I know of. However you could use something like a Stack and simply Push() and Pop() off this to go up and down your markers in order:

```
FileStream file = new FileStream(...);

try {
  Stack<long> markers = new Stack<long>();

  markers.Push(file.Position);

  file.Read(....);

  file.Seek(markers.Pop(),SeekOrigin.Begin);
} finally {
  file.Close();
}
```

Another idea based on a Dictionary:

```
FileStream file = new FileStream(...);

try {
  Dictionary<string,long> markers = new Dictionary<string,long>();

  markers.Add("thebeginning",file.Position);

  file.Read(....);

  file.Seek(markers["thebeginning"],SeekOrigin.Begin);
} finally {
  file.Close();
}
```

Comment: +1, nice solution, but I assume you meant that the Stack-initialization is in another scope, i.e. class-level? ;)

Comment: Not necessarily, depends on where you want to use it, here the stack is immediately in the same scope as the file i/o calls. Stack<> is just one solution too, you could use a Dictionary<string,long> and actually give NAMED markers instead, it's all gravy :)

Comment: +1, like that solution! Also possible: Subclass the FileStream and add that stack into that class

Comment: Thank you, will try it and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a `StreamReader` you are using, you have to keep in mind that it is not exactly a `Stream` itself, but you can access its `BaseStream` property:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("test.txt");
Stream stream = reader.BaseStream;
```

It will give you your current position in the stream:

```
long pos = stream.Position;
```

And it will allow you to move back there:

```
stream.Seek(pos, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```